# bash, treat piped commands as one to capture output

Tags: bash, pipe

Say I have a set of piped commands in bash:

```
mysqldump mydatabase  |   head -1100   | tail -n 100
```

What is the correct / best way to treat that as one command, so I can capture the output.

I tried enclosing the commands in  backticks (which as I understand opens a new shell, which seems unnecessary), but got an error.

```
`mysqldump mydatabase  |   head -1100   | tail -n 100 ` > output.txt  


error mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
```

Not sure if the error is related to the bash commands or the mysql (it worked before I added the backticks).

Anyway, I am more interested in how I can treat the piped commands as one / group them for capturing.

Comment: If you just want to put the pipe commands' results in a file.Juse use: mysqldump mydatabase  |   head -1100   | tail -n 100 > output.txt. Absolutely no need to put the `**`

Comment: Having `\`` is dangerous in this case rather. Imaging if the command produces `rm -rf / ` as output string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stdout of the left hand command is acting as the stdin of the right hand command, so `mysqldump mydatabase  |   head -1100   | tail -n 100  > output.txt` should work.

If you really to "make it clear", this should work.   `( mysqldump mydatabase  |   head -1100   | tail -n 100 ) > output.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Each command in your line takes some input and returns an output, so you could see it like a chain where data is passed through.

If you want your results to be displayed in the console you just write

```
mysqldump mydatabase | head -1100 | tail -n 100
```

otherwise to have it on file you redirect output to a file, like so

```
mysqldump mydatabase | head -1100 | tail -n 100 > output.txt
```

[More info](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) [about redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating two `pipes` you can use `sed` to find sections of line numbers

```
    mysqldump mydatabase | sed -n '1000,1100p' > output.txt
```

Comment: That is unnecessary. Redirecting the output of a pipeline is equivalent to redirecting the output of a function call, executing the same pipeline, only the function call creates more overhead.

Comment: Maybe I should've asked why the OP said he wants to 'treat piped commands as one.'  If it were a case where he needed use the same pipe multiple times in a script, the function would be necessary.